# Purpose of backup fuse in SPD

Tags: fuses, surge-protection

I am trying to understand the main purpose of backup fuse used in SPD (Surge Protection device). Is this used to protect the SPD from high AC current but still allowing surge current to pass or does it has different reason. I tried searching but with no luck I am positing it here.

I also found following picture which explains about the Fuse F1 and F2 but cant figure out much.

[image]

Can anyone explain me about this or provide some links where I can read more about it.

Comment: where is the load and where the surge protector?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, i dont have that details, for now I am just trying to understand the purpose of backup fuse (F2) for SPD.

Comment: That's difficult to understand without knowing wher the current comes from and where it goes.

Comment: ok, I dont have a specific application. I am jsut trying to understand why is F2 placed in series (before) SPD.

Comment: Lightning surge voltage protection can short the feeder (like an SCR) so it must be fused upstream of the SPD for Line to Line and Line to Earth. What's missing here are the SPDs

Comment: I recall a senior design used a gas tube SPD on a circuit board for an offline ACDC supply and a tiny transient from lightning nearby ( not a direct hit) triggered the little gas tube and burnt a crater in the FR4 because it wasn't fused. Gas tubes are like Diacs or SCR's= negative resistance devices with a higher threshold voltage

Answer (score 1):

From: [Installation Instructions](http://www.sahkonumerot.fi/3208031/doc/installationinstruction/)

[image: Surge Protector]

F2 is a parallel backup fuse.  If I ≤ 250A F1 will open.  But if I > 250A, F1 and F2 will open to protect circuitry.

From [Overvoltage Protection of Low Voltage Systems](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xIzurwS5LR0C&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=%22surge%20protection%22%20%22backup%20fuse%22&source=bl&ots=bYgsJJrZ-U&sig=ACfU3U0uhK1qhyHtWmZj12PWlyXF8vc_GA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif1peTi-ngAhVKJt8KHQhSC-s4KBDoATAEegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%22surge%20protection%22%20%22backup%20fuse%22&f=false)  By Peter Hasse:

> For the TN-system overcurrent and residual protective devices are permitted for 'protection in case of indirect contact'. Lightning current and surge arresters (classes B and C) may only be installed behind overcurrent protective devices for 'protection in case of indirect contact' to safeguard measures of personnel protection also in case of an arrester fault.

There is more there in the Hasse link, but F2 is there to protect the circuit from a current surge (class C) or a lightning strike (class B).  You also have over-voltage protection (class D).  Relative Reference: IEC 61008-1.

Comment: thanks a lot, book from Hasse was really helpfull to understand the concept of backup fuse for SPD..